# Angular: Todo list won't load if i filter results

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a (very basic) todo app with Angular and if i try to filter result from an array imported from services it won't filter results real time, and it works only if i open another page (it's a spa) and go back to the todo list. If i omit the part with filter in constructor it returns me the list correctly.

**todos.service.ts**

```
import { Todo } from "./models/todo";

export let arrayTodos: Todo[] = [
  {
    id: 34875487532,
    title: 'prova1',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 545463,
    title: 'prova2',
    completed: false
  }
];

let id: number = 0;

export function getTodos(): Promise<Todo[]> {
  return new Promise((success, error) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      success(arrayTodos);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

export function aggiungiTodo(title: string) {
  return new Promise<void>((success, error) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      id++;
      let newTodo: Todo = {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        completed: false
      };
      //arrayTodos = [...arrayTodos, newTodo];
      arrayTodos.push(newTodo);
      //console.log(arrayTodos);
      success();
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

**todo.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './models/todo';
import * as TodoService from './todos.service';

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="input-area">
      <input placeholder="inserisci una task" type="text" (keyup)="getTesto($event)">
      <button class="addTask" type="button" (click)="addTodo()">+</button>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo.title}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class TodoPage implements OnInit {
  todos!: Todo[];
  titoloNuovoTodo!: string;

  constructor() {
    /* TodoService.getTodos().then((res: Todo[])=>this.todos = res.filter(todo => !todo.completed)); */
    TodoService.getTodos().then((res: Todo[]) => {
      this.todos = res.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
    });
  }

  getTesto(event: Event): void {
    const target = <HTMLInputElement>event.target;
    this.titoloNuovoTodo = target.value;
  }

  addTodo() {
    console.log(this.todos);

    TodoService.aggiungiTodo(this.titoloNuovoTodo);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you don't do data initialization in the `constructor`. You do it in `ngOnInit`. That should work.

EDIT: I also strongly recommend you use an Observable as opposed to your Promise (you can use `from` to convert it), and then use the `async` pipe in your template when you need to display your Todos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It didn't work  It's strange, because if i don't use filter it works perfectly.
Anyway I solved pushing the todos inside the property todos. This is the only solution that works with the knowledge i have rn.